# Need help getting the numbers to double all the way to the middle

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a pyramid that will double all the way to the center.

The code is producing this.

```
         1
       1 2 1
     1 2 3 2 1
   1 2 3 4 3 2 1
```

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

for (i = 1; i<= lines; i++){ // sets rows (lines)

    for (j = a; j >= 1; j--){ // dead space on left
        System.out.printf(str," ");
    }

    for (k = 1; k != i; k++){ //left side numbers
        String str1 = "" + k;
        System.out.printf(str, str1);
    }

    a--;

    for (int l = k; l >=1; l--){ // right side numbers
        String  str2 = "" + l;
        System.out.printf(str, str2);
    }
}
```

I expected it to look like this.

```
                               1                            
                           1   2   1                        
                       1   2   4   2   1                    
                   1   2   4   8   4   2   1                
               1   2   4   8  16   8   4   2   1            
           1   2   4   8  16  32  16   8   4   2   1        
       1   2   4   8  16  32  64  32  16   8   4   2   1    
   1   2   4   8  16  32  64 128  64  32  16   8   4   2   1
```

Answer (score 2):

`k` and `l` should be used as exponents rather than as the numbers you are printing.

```
int lines = 8;
String str = "%4s"; //pads each number to 4 spaces
for (int i = 1; i <= lines; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < lines - i; j++) //Replaced a with lines - i
    {

        System.out.printf(str, " ");
    }

    for (int k = 1; k != i; k++)
    {
        //replaced k with 2 ^ (k - 1)
        String str1 = "" + (int)(Math.pow(2, k - 1)); 
        System.out.printf(str, str1);
    }
    for (int l = i; l >= 1; l--)
    {
        //replaced l with 2 ^ (l - 1)
        String str2 = "" + (int)(Math.pow(2, l - 1));
        System.out.printf(str, str2);
    }
    System.out.println(); //added newline between each line
}
```

Output:

```
                               1
                           1   2   1
                       1   2   4   2   1
                   1   2   4   8   4   2   1
               1   2   4   8  16   8   4   2   1
           1   2   4   8  16  32  16   8   4   2   1
       1   2   4   8  16  32  64  32  16   8   4   2   1
   1   2   4   8  16  32  64 128  64  32  16   8   4   2   1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that dynamically adjusts the spacing as needed.

The code uses `<<`/`>>` bit-shifting to double/halve the numbers.

```
public static void printPyramidOfSquares(int lines) {
    if (lines < 0 || lines > 63)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    int width = Long.toString(1L << (lines - 1)).length();
    for (int line = 1; line <= lines; line++) {
        if (line < lines)
            System.out.printf("%" + (lines - line) * (width + 1) + "s", "");
        long val = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i < line; i++, val <<= 1)
            System.out.printf("%" + width + "d ", val);
        for (int i = 1; i < line; i++, val >>= 1)
            System.out.printf("%" + width + "d ", val);
        System.out.printf("%" + width + "d%n", val);
    }
}
```

*Test*

```
printPyramidOfSquares(4);
printPyramidOfSquares(5);
printPyramidOfSquares(8);
```

*Output*

```
      1
    1 2 1
  1 2 4 2 1
1 2 4 8 4 2 1
             1
          1  2  1
       1  2  4  2  1
    1  2  4  8  4  2  1
 1  2  4  8 16  8  4  2  1
                              1
                          1   2   1
                      1   2   4   2   1
                  1   2   4   8   4   2   1
              1   2   4   8  16   8   4   2   1
          1   2   4   8  16  32  16   8   4   2   1
      1   2   4   8  16  32  64  32  16   8   4   2   1
  1   2   4   8  16  32  64 128  64  32  16   8   4   2   1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution that calculates each row / col using the formula: "`val = 2^(row - |lines - col - 1|)`". It automatically adjusts the spacing using log base 10 to calculate the number of digits.

```
int s = 2 + (int) Math.log10(1 << lines);
IntStream.range(0, lines)
    .mapToObj(r -> IntStream.range(0, 2 * lines - 1)
        .map(c -> r - Math.abs(lines - c - 1))
        .mapToObj(v -> v >= 0 ? String.format("%" + s + "d", 1 << v) : " ".repeat(s))
        .collect(Collectors.joining()))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: For this assignment we have to use the formatting. I could also see some better ways if that wasn't  a requirement. Sorry I should have noted that